# Updating extending user form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a CustomUserModel within my models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None,is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have email address")
        user_obj = self.model(email = self.normalize_email(email))
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a password")

        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)

        return user_obj

    def create_staffuser(self,email,password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email, password=password,is_staff=True)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email, password=password, is_staff=True, is_admin=True)

        return user



class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # email and password are required by default
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active


class Customer(models.Model):

    GENDER = (
            ('Male', 'Male'),
            ('Female', 'Female'),
            )

    TITLE = (
            ('Mr', 'Mr'),
            ('Mrs', 'Mrs'),
            ('Miss', 'Miss'),
            ('Ms', 'Ms'),
            ('Dr', 'Dr'),
            ('Sir', 'Sir'),
            ('Madam', 'Madam'),
            )



    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=TITLE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True,default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    country = CountryField()
    birth_year = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=GENDER)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_purchase = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

Within my views.py I have an view that I want to update users/customers, see below for the views

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def CustomerProfile(request, pk):

    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    user_form = RegisterForm(instance=user)
    customer_form = CustomerProfileForm(instance=customer)

    if 'edit_customer' in request.POST:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user_form = RegisterForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
            customer_form = CustomerProfileForm(request.POST,instance=request.user.customer)

            if user_form.is_valid() and customer_form.is_valid():
                user = user_form.save()
                customer = customer_form.save(commit=False)
                customer.user = user
                customer.save()
                return redirect('/')

    return render(request, 'accounts/customer_profile.html', {'user_form': user_form,'customer_form':customer_form})
```

See below for my template for the mentioned view

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <h5>Customer Profile</h5>
    </div>



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}

                  {{user_form|crispy}}
                {{customer_form|crispy}}

                <hr>
                <input type="submit" name="Update">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem  that I am receiving is that, if I were to edit the customer/user in the form, it will not save the changes.

Is there a way of resolving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have not saved the user form

@login_required(login_url='login')
def CustomerProfile(request, pk):

```
customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
user_form = RegisterForm(instance=user)
customer_form = CustomerProfileForm(instance=customer)

if 'edit_customer' in request.POST:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = RegisterForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        customer_form = CustomerProfileForm(request.POST,instance=request.user.customer)

        if user_form.is_valid() and customer_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.save() #<-------------------------------Add this 
            customer = customer_form.save(commit=False)
            customer.user = user
            customer.save()
            return redirect('/')

return render(request, 'accounts/customer_profile.html', {'user_form': user_form,'customer_form':customer_form})
```